# PHP run jquery using guzzle framework

Tags: php, jquery, web-scraping, guzzle

I have elemenet that is changing on other site trigger click.
Is it possible to run jQuery script using php guzzle and then take new element value into my stored variable?
That's my code

```
    <?php
# scraping books to scrape: https://books.toscrape.com/
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $httpClient->get('webpage');
$htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();
//add this line to suppress any warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$prices = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="price"]//p[@class="our_price_display"]//span[@class="price"]');

foreach ($prices as $key => $price) {
echo $price->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. When you download content via guzzle (or curl or anything else) the data you get back is simply treated as a string by php. There is no JavaScript execution environment present. You'd need something like a headless browser for that.

Comment: Thanks very much.
Can you explain me more about 'headless browser' or give a visual example?
Thanks again

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser

Comment: Will be possible to integrate something with PHP and send data back to my webpage?